# Java Switch between cases and repeating them

Tags: java, switch-statement

I coded this switch statement:

```
int up = 1;
switch(up){
case 1:
//some methods get called - if statement with break
up = 0;
case 0: 
//some methods get called - if statement with break
up = 1;
}
```

What I expected from my code:
It should run from case 1 to case 0 and then to case 1 to case 0 and so on until I call break;.

What actually happens:
case 1 and case 2 are running once and don't repeat.

What's wrong?

Comment: change of variable `up`in within the switch wont affect the follwing cases. here both cases are running because you dont have break. also for the code to loop, you should put it in any loop like for/while..

Comment: switch-case is not a loop

Comment: A switch is not  a loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I thought I have created a loop so the cases are in a loop until there is a break , after i run case 1 it is switching to case 0 and then i expected it to move to case one because I set up to 1.

Comment: After you run case 1 it is going to case 0 because there is no `break` after case 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaking the `break` used in [loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) with the `break` used in the [switch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

```
    int up = 1;
    DO_WHILE_LOOP : do{
        switch(up){
        case 1:
            up = 0;
            if (yourCondition) break DO_WHILE_LOOP; break;
        case 0: 
            up = 1;
            if (yourCondition) break DO_WHILE_LOOP; break;
        }
    } while (true);
```

Here is a way to do it.

You're looping with a DoWhile loop and testing `yourCondition`. If it is filled, you're `break`ing from the `DO_WHILE_LOOP` (name we gave to our "infinite-loop")

The loop is infinite until the condition is filled.

***INFO :***

A simple break, without the `DO_WHILE_LOOP` annotation would have worked. But for the clarity, I think this is the best to do it.